# Show that f is continuous at all c ∈ R \ Z and discontinuous at all c ∈ Z.

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, continuity

For any x ∈ R define the floor of x, denoted [x],to be the largest integer y with
y ≤ x. Then define a function f : R → R by f(x) =[x]. Show that f is continuous
at all c ∈ R \ Z and discontinuous at all c ∈ Z.

Not sure how to even start the question. How do I even define the floor of x? (Probably basic but I am stuck).

Comment: "How do I even define the floor of x?" It says right there: "the largest integer y with y ≤ x"

Comment: If $c\in\mathbb Z$ and $0<\epsilon<1$, what is $[c-\epsilon]$?

Comment: Thanks. Thats what confused me, I thought it was asking me  to define it but then it gave their definition for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks obvious.   For $x$ not an integer, $[x] < x < [x]+1$, let $\epsilon =min (\frac{x-[x]}{2},\frac{1+[x]-x}{2})\gt 0$, then for $(x-\epsilon \lt y \lt x+\epsilon)$, $f(x)=[x]$ a constant.  Therefore $f(x)$ is continuous.  For $x$ an integer, for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, $ [x-\epsilon]=x-1$, while $[x+\epsilon]=x$, so not continuous at $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It might be fairly obvious to others but I honestly don't have the best grasp on Analysis.

Comment: Also for x not an integer part, did you mean to write x or c? Also how does that show its discontinuous at all c belonging to Z?

Comment: Actually it makes sense now.